# Angular - Como pasarle a una funcion un formulario como parametro

Tags: angular, formularios, webforms

Quiero que al pulsar un **boton**  cambie ciertos estados de los **inputs**       de un **formulario en concreto** como es la posibilidad de escribir en ellos, que por defecto lo tengo **desactivado**

**Esta funcion** deberia de llevar un **parametro de tipo form** creo.

```
activarEdicion() {
  console.log('Edicion habilitada')
}
```

El **form** en cuestion:

```
<form #fomDetailUser="ngForm" *ngIf="mostrar" >
   <h1>Usuario Encontrado</h1>
   <label>Nombre: </label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" #nombre="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.nombre" READONLY>
   <br>
   <label>Apellido 1: </label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="apel_1" #apel_1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.apel_1" READONLY>
   <br>
   <label>Apellido 2: </label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="apel_2" #apel_2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.apel_2" READONLY>
   <br>
   <label>Email: </label>
   <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" READONLY>
   <br>
   <label>Fecha Nacimiento: </label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fecha_nacimiento" #fecha_nacimiento="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.fecha_nacimiento" READONLY>
   <br>
   <!-- Slider -->
   <div class="section" data-toggle="buttons">
       <button class="btn btn-info" (click)="activarEdicion()"> Editar</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Y basicamente quiero que al pulsar el `button` Editar cambien los el atributo `readonly` para que pueda ser editado.

**Recuerdo** que a la funcion que llama el `button` habia que pasarle un form o algo de eso.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que para pasarle el formulario a una función, o en realidad para que formulario sea un propoerty de tu componente y esté vsible para cualquier función dle mismo, tendrías que usar reactive forms.

Con ngModel me parece que podés hacer algo como:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" #nombre="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.nombre" [readonly]="soloLectura">
```

Y en el `.ts` inicializar un atributo `soloLectura = true` y en `activarEdicion()`:

```
...
soloLectura = false;
...
```